# How do I get iPad (iOS 7) to use the email aliases I have set up on gmail

Tags: ipad, email, ios, gmail

I have an iPad with iOS7. This is set up with 2 email accounts (gmail and ISP default).
I want to use the "Contact Us" option on one of my apps, but this offers me the options of using either of the mail logon email addresses.
I NEVER use either of these, and don't disclose these to anyone (so I can easily change when they get too much spam).

My question is how do I get the iPad to use the email aliases I have set up on gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in iOS 7: This works when you have an authenticated alias set up as your default in Gmail.

Settings → Mail, Contacts, Calendars → Add Account → Other

On "Account" Page:

- Email: you@personaldomain.com
- Password: Your personal domain password
- **Incoming Server**: imap.gmail.com
- Username: Your Gmail username
- Password: Your Gmail password
- **Outgoing Server**: pop.gmail.com
- Username: Your Gmail username
- Password: Your Gmail password

Answer (score 0):

You can set your email up using IMAP. This lets you specify the email address (the alias you want to use) as well as the authenticating account (your actual email address and password).

Go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Add Account > Other > Add Mail Account. Then enter the email address you want to use. When you click Next, the next screen allows you to specify the username (your actual email address) and password.

Answer (score 0):

It requires some cheating if you want to have multiple From addresses available for a single account. http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2013/03/24/multiple-email-aliases-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Using IMAP instead of the Gmail configurator is the best current solution, at least for iOS 7. See this nice [blog post](http://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2014/01/using-gmail-aliases-in-ios-7/), courtesy of Nathan Jones, that provides a detailed solution with screenshots.

From Nathan's blog post (step 12):

> Touch *Add Another Email*… to add as many e-mails as you want. (Remember
>   these have to be preauthorized by Google.)

Once you've added all of the aliases that you've already set up in Gmail, the aliases can be used in iOS to send or reply to emails.